# cursor is not visible on click of left and right arrows in Mozilla

Tags: jquery-terminal

I'm using jquery terminal plugin and I found that when I want to edit the entered command, the cursor is hiding and it's not visible in Mozilla but the text is inserting. Did I missed anything ..?

Comment: This seems to be a bug, you can report it here https://github.com/jcubic/jquery.terminal/issues/new?template=bug.md

Comment: The fix is in devel branch on GitHub you only need to use new CSS file https://github.com/jcubic/jquery.terminal/blob/devel/css/jquery.terminal.min.css if you use webpack you will need to wait for next version, to be released soon.

Comment: new version 2.5.0 got released it include the fix.

Comment: Thank you for the Quick and accurate response.